# What is happening in this C++ code in C++ (Exponent Function)

Tags: c++

```
 int power(int baseNum, int powNum) {
     int result = 1;
 for(int i = 0; i < powNum; i++) {
       result = result * baseNum
}
 return result;
}

 int main()

{

  cout <<power(2 , 3);

   return 0;
```

It's from this [YouTube Video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZZ2VFnBLRmE)

So what I don't understand is how he picks **int result = 1;** out of nowhere? Why not = 2?

Why **int i = 0** , why not = 1 ?

In the video part "Let's break it down" he says the first Result is **1**

But isn't it 0?

First loop is 0
Next loop is 1
3rd loop is 2
and then it exits because it's 3 < 3
right?

If someone can make a transcription of the loops will be great so I can see exactly what's going on.

And the last thing how we make these calculations **result = result * baseNum** with the loops so we can get to 8.

I just started learning C++.

Comment: (1) the code would be a lot easier to understand if it were formatted properly (2) step away from C++ for a moment and think about how to calculate `baseNum ** powNum` by hand, using pencil & paper.

Comment: please one question per question. And do the maths first. If you calculate `5^3`, would you start with `2` ?

Answer (score -1):

> So what I don't understand is how he picks int result = 1; out of nowhere? Why not = 2?

That is so it's not always 0 if he multiplies the result in the for loop. 0 * 2 --> 0

**About the for loop itself:**

1. Iteration: 1 * 2 --> 2 / i = 0
2. Iteration: 2 * 2 --> 4 / i = 1
3. Iteration: 4 * 2 --> 8 / i = 2
4. Iteration: i = 3 / is not smaller than 3 leaves the for-loop

At the end he leaves the function and returns the result which is now 8.

For the for-loop, getting the the power of 3 with a base of 2, gives back the same as if you would just multiple 2 * 2 * 2.

That is exactly what the for-loop does you go through and do the first multiplication 1 * 2, on the second iteration you calculate you multiply the result again 2 * 2, then you go through again and calculate the next iteration 4 * 2 which then gets you the desired result